# How to get width and height of iPhone/iPad using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, resolution

I need to get the width and height of iPhone/iPad using MonoTouch.

How to get programmatically?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get the screen size of the device, call `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds`. It returns a `RectangleF` with the screen size.

Answer (score 9):

To get width use,

```
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width
```

To get height use,

```
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Answer (score 4):

You use **UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds** to get the **point** size of the screen. 
It returns the point value of the screen, not the pixel size.

**UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale** which return 1.0 pixels per point for non-retina displays, and 2.0 pixels per point for retina displays.

**UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale** will get the width in pixels.